# AWS .tgs file is downloaded as a .gz archive (aws, js)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to s3 in this way.

This is the server code:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: `${process.env.AWS_FOLDER_NAME}/${bucketName}`,
    Key: fileName,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL:'public-read'
}

const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)
return signedUrl
```

This is the client code:

```
const {signedUrl, err} = await response.json()

await fetch(signedUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: file.body,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.fileType,
        'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    }})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Here `file.body` is `reader.result` from this code

```
const reader = new FileReader()
  
reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
reader.onerror = reject;
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

All this works very well! But yesterday I uploaded a .tgs file in this way (it's a telegram sticker) and when I try to download it from s3, I don't download the file itself.

Instead this, s3 give me the .gz archive inside which my original .tgs file lies. Moreover, this is a file inside the .gz archive without the .tgs extension.

[image]

The file itself in s3 looks quite normal
[image: Tgs sticker on aws]

**I want s3 to just give me the file. How should I do it?**

Answer (score 0):

`tgs` file is actually a `gz` file, you can just rename it from `AnimatedSticker.gz` to `AnimatedSticker.tgs`